# Spinner items lost on navigate change in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have created an Android Studio project and i have `MainActivity`, `FirstFragment` and `SecondFragment`. On the FirstFragment I have an spinner element. When the app starts the spinner is filled with values, when I switch from the First to the second Fragment and back, the values are gone.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        PublicCameras Cameras = new PublicCameras();
        //get the spinner from the xml.
        Spinner dropdown = findViewById(R.id.cameraList); // This element loses his values when navigating to SecondFragment and back
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Cameras.GetNamesEn());
        dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

FirstFragment

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);



        view.findViewById(R.id.button_first).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(FirstFragment.this)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

SecondFragment

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        view.findViewById(R.id.button_second).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(SecondFragment.this)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_SecondFragment_to_FirstFragment);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I would like to point out that on rotating the values are being set again because of re-entering the function onCreateOptionsMenu. What is the best practice to keep values on a layout change?

Thank you for your time !

Comment: In you're case you need to override`onSavedInstance` and `OnRestoreInstance` methods in you're fragments and add the list into the `OnSavedInstance` method and restore them in `OnRestoreInstance`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply ! Could you please provide any information on how to achieve that or is there any better way to do the navigation between layouts? Best regards!

Comment: I can see you're getting the spinner items from a model class right..??

Comment: Correct, the class returns type String[]

Comment: I guess you're using navigation component in you're activity and made the first fragment as the start activity right and from this fragment you're moving to second fragment right.

Comment: Yes that is true, it is a basic activity project

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this issue cause when you move from one fragment to other android destorys the fragment and recreates that fragment when returned back this happens in the screen orientation case too. In order to handle this override `OnSavedInstance` method in you're code

There is a little hack you can make it work.

first override

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putStringArray("YOUR_KEY", "YOUR_OBJECT");//chnage this with you're object name
}
```

Now in you're `onViewCreated` use the SavedInstance variable and get that stringArray using the key and pass this to the spinner.

Try this and if you faced any issue do comment.

Comment: Hello, so i have placed the override function in the MainActivity with the following content 
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        PublicCameras Cameras = new PublicCameras();
        outState.putStringArray("cameraList",Cameras.GetNamesEn());//chnage this with you're object name
outState.putStringArray requirers String key, String[] so for the key i have changed " R.id.cameraList" to " cameraList" but in the result the values are yet again not saved. Also i have tried same thing in the FirstFragment. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I answered you're question with the utmost knowledge I have on android. So, I suggest you to make a research about the same issue on your own with the idea I gave to you.

Comment: I'll take some time to work on this and get back to you with the working code